# Sed replace words in quotes

Tags: sed

I have file which contains lines like below. Wanted to replace the words in quotes after `-s` and `-e`. Tried with `sed` but didn't work.

**File Contents**

```
abc -s "today" -e "today" def
abc -s "yesterday" -e "yesterday" def
abc -s "3 days ago" -e "3 days ago" def
```

**Tried Command**

```
sed 's|-s "*" -e "*"|-s "1" -e "2"|g' <filename>
```

**Required output**

```
abc -s "1" -e "2" def
abc -s "1" -e "2" def
abc -s "1" -e "2" def
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue with your own attempt is that `"*"` means "match zero or more double quotes, followed by yet another double quote".  This is because `*` is a regular expression modifier that means "zero or more of the previous expression".  This means that `"*"` would match strings like `"`, `""`, `"""` etc.

Apart from that, you needlessly use a different delimiter for the `s///` command, and you use `/g` at the end even though you do not expect to do more than one replacement per line.  But these are just issues relating to style.

---

There are several ways to do this with `sed`, but all of them must match a string between double quotes in one way or another.  A string between double quotes can be match by the regular expression `"[^"]*"`, i.e. "match a double quote, and then zero or more characters that are not double quotes, followed by another double quote character".

```
$ sed -e 's/-s "[^"]*"/-s "1"/' -e 's/-e "[^"]*"/-e "2"/' file
abc -s "1" -e "2" def
abc -s "1" -e "2" def
abc -s "1" -e "2" def
```

The above uses two *separate* expressions to match and replace the strings after the given option, which also means that

- it doesn't matter in which order the options are given in the input (`-s "whatever"` will always be replaced by `-s "1"` and `-e "whatever"` will always be replaced by `-e "2"`),
- it makes it indifferent to the number of spaces between the options (change e.g. `-s "[^"]*"` to `-s *"[^"]*"` to also allow multiple spaces between the option and the option argument),
- it doesn't matter whether or not there may be other options present (nor how these are ordered in relation to the `-s` and `-e` options), and
- if only one of `-s` and `-e` is present, but not the other, the option and the option-argument present would be replaced.

If you additionally need to do the replacements only on lines that start with `abc`:

```
sed -e '/^abc/{' -e 's/-s "[^"]*"/-s "1"/' -e 's/-e "[^"]*"/-e "2"/' -e '}' file
```

or without all those `-e` options in the `sed` command:

```
sed '/^abc/{ s/-s "[^"]*"/-s "1"/; s/-e "[^"]*"/-e "2"/; }' file
```

Change `/^abc/` to `/^abc.*def$/` if you additionally need to make sure that the lines you modify ends with `def`.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation

Comment: Today i have come across new scenario, where instead of double quotes i got contents with single quotes. I have tried with above example i didnt get the output. I tried solution as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52723293/how-to-grep-everything-between-single-quotes by using '\(.*\)' but vain, shall i post that as a new question. please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Sed uses regular expressions, not wildcard patterns. `*` means "repeat the preceding element zero or more times", and you need to repeat `.` which means "anything":

```
sed 's/-s ".*" -e ".*"/-s "1" -e "2"/'
```

Comment: could you please check i didnt get he output

Comment: @upkar: Sorry, a missing `*`.